# Passing an instance of a class which implementing two interfaces as two different subtypes

Tags: java, oop, interface, polymorphism

If I have:

```
public interface One{
    public void method1();
}

public interface Two{
    public void method2();
}

public class AClass implements One, Two{

}

public static void aDiffMethod1(One o){
    o.method1();
}

public static void aDiffMethod2(Two t){
    t.method2();
}

public static void main(String[] args){
     AClass a = new AClass();
     aDiffMethod1(a);
     aDiffMethod2(b);
}
```

Sometimes in my code I will pass an instance of AClass using the fact it is a subtype of the interface One (in other words, the parameter type of the method will be One and I will pass the type AClass) and at other times I may pass the AClass object knowing its a subtype of the interface Two (the parameter type of the method im passing to is Two, so I pass AClass as a subtype of Two).

Is it ok to pass an instance of AClass into different methods under the guise of being a subtype of different interfaces?

Is this what they mean by programming to the interface- so it is fine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is the whole point of interfaces.

Methods that only accept interface `One` will only ever call `method1`, so this is safe. methods that only accept interface `Two` will only ever call `method2`, so again, this is safe.

Comment: and is this what they mean by the phrase programming to the interface?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Programming to use the object as if it is the interface.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is fine. If a method is expecting an interface implementation, then your AClass fulfills that contract.

Programming to the interface rather than to the implementation is a design approach where you group behavioural operations into your interfaces rather than having it located in your main class.